# C++ What type of pointer should I use to store output address of `algorithm` `remove` function?

Tags: c++, pointers, variables

I'm trying to store the address returned by the `algorithm` `remove` function in C++ in a variable, but have failed to find one.  I've tried `int*` and `char*`.  Both threw errors.

Using Visual Studio CL, the error is:
`error C2440: '=': cannot convert from '_FwdIt' to 'int *'`

Using MinGW, the error is:
`cannot convert '__gnu_cxx::__normal_iterator<char*, std::__cxx11::basic_string<char> >' to 'int*' in assignment`

How should I store such an address?

The code I'm trying:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <iostream>
#include <string>
#include <algorithm>
using namespace std;

int main (void) {
  string line ("This is an example sentence.");
  int* newEOL;
  newEOL = remove(line.begin(), line.end(), ' ');
  printf("%p\n", newEOL);
}
```

Comment: `std::remove` returns an iterator, not a pointer. And an `int*` is most certainly not what you can use to point to an element of a `std::string`. The correct type would be `std::string::iterator` (or use `auto`)

Comment: @SauravKumar that is a horrible suggestion, `void*` is barely ever the correct solution to a problem in C++

Answer (score 5):

Why do you think it's a pointer?

As evidenced here: https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/algorithm/remove
it's an iterator, which can be implemented as a pointer, but doesn't have to.

You can use the `auto` keyword if you don't want to specify the type explicitly.